# Создать объект из  JSON строки

Tags: json, javascript, объекты

У меня есть переменная в формате **JSON**

```
var json ='{\
    "login":"11",\
    "la":"48.30369",
    "lo":"38.033502",\
    "login":"12",\
    "la":"48.40369",\
    "lo":"38.033502",\
    "login":"13",\
    "la":"48.70369",\
    "lo":"38.033502"\
}';
```

Я пытаюсь создать объект, чтобы можно было вывести все его элементы

```
var a = JSON.parse(json);
var o = {login:a.lo, 
            la:a.la, 
            lo:a.lo};
for (var k in o){
    var b = {login:a.lo[k], 
            la:a.la[k], 
            lo:a.lo[k]};
}
document.write(b);
```

В результате   выводит `[object Object]` - как мне вывести ассоциативный массив корректно?
Возможно я изначально пошел не верным путем но   мне нужно чтобы на выходе был массив

**`[{login:11[0], la:значение[0], значение[0]},
{login:12[1], la:значение[1], lo:значение[1]},
{login:13[2], la:значение[2], lo:значение[2]}
 ....
{login:o.lo[i], la:значение[i], lo:значение[i]}]`** - Все значения которые взяты из **var json**

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться!

Comment: document.wtite  xD

Внимательно печатали?

Comment: Зачем тут цикл for in? Это не ассоциативный массив а Object

Comment: @vkovalchuk88, в джаваскрипте массив и объект это Object. for in будет работать для того и для другого. 

@CBETOBuT, с каждой итерацией цикла вы создаете новый объект b, а не дополняете старый. document.write(b) распечатет тип переменной b, а не ее содержимое.

Comment: и стринг и намбер - это обджект:)

Comment: @vkovalchuk88, нет. `[]` - это массив. `{}` - это объект или, если хотите, ассоциативный массив. К элементам массива можно обращаться по индексам (а к полям объекта нельзя), к полям объекта можно обращаться по именам. Хотя тип и там и там - object.

Comment: Объект, что это чуть больше чем ассоц. массив, поведение похожее, но это немного разные штуки, вывод объекта не выводит элементы массива, длина 0, свойства есть унаследованые, собственные, не сортируются ключи как в php.

Comment: Товарищи я немного видоизменил задачу, прошу помочь мне: [JSON строку в ассоциативный массив JS](http://hashcode.ru/questions/262130/javascript-json-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-js)

Answer (score 1):

У вас неправильное значение в переменной :)

```
var t = {
    "login" : 11,
    "la" : 48.30369,
    "lo" : 38.033502,
    "login" : 12,
    "la" : 48.40369,
    "lo" : 38.033502,
    "login" : 13,
    "la" : 48.70369,
    "lo" : 38.03350,
}

/* result => */ Object {login: 13, la: 48.70369, lo: 38.0335}
```

В фигурных скобках задаётся объект, в формате :value, так вот - если указывается ключ повторно, то старый просто перезатирается

Потому у вас в переменной описание объекта лишь из последних трёх строк, а первые шесть - теряются

Запихните в переменную (раз уж вы её используете) вот такое значение:

```
'[{ "login" : 11, "la" : 48.30369, "lo" : 38.033502},{"login" : 12, "la" : 48.40369, "lo" : 38.033502},{ "login" : 13, "la" : 48.70369, "lo" : 38.03350}]'
```

JSON.parse с такой строкой как раз выдаст массив с объектами

---

PS: вместо document.write [используйте console.log](http://habrahabr.ru/post/114483/)

Answer (score 0):

Дайте угадаю, вы подаёте на вход это:

```
var b = {login:a.lo[k], 
        la:a.la[k], 
        lo:a.lo[k]};
```

а на выходе хотите получить это:

```
"{'login':'bla','la':'bla','lo':bla}"
```

Тогда вам нужна функция [JSON.stringify()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ie/cc836459(v=vs.94).aspx). И да, забудьте про `document.write()`. Откуда только повылезало столько адептов этого доисторического... метода? Третий раз за месяц уже.

Comment: var json ='{"login":"11","la":"48.30369","lo":"38.033502","login":"12","la":"48.40369","lo":"38.033502","login":"13","la":"48.70369","lo":"38.033502"}';
var a = JSON.parse(json);
var o = {login:a.lo, 
   la:a.la, 
   lo:a.lo};
for (var k in o){
 var b = {login:a.lo[k], 
   la:a.la[k], 
   lo:a.lo[k]};
   b.toString(k);
   var c = JSON.stringify(b);
}

 document.write(c);

выдает {}  - помему я опять что то не то делаю

Comment: мне на выходе нужен ассоциативный массив чтобы я мог обратиться к любому элементу

Comment: А что в document.write не то? Откуда инфа?

Comment: Так `b` уже является ассоциативным массивом. Вы можете обращаться к любому его элементу так: `b['login']`. Или вам как-то по другому надо? Опишите подробнее.

Comment: мне нужно чтобы на выходе был массив 
 [{login:11[0], la:значение[0], значение[0]},{login:12[1], la:значение[1], lo:значение[1]},{login:13[2], la:значение[2], lo:значение[2]} ....{login:o.lo[i], la:значение[i], lo:значение[i]}];

Comment: Тут массива вообще нету фигурные скобки - это объект.

Чтобы получить массив этих данных 0, 1, 2. Исходный должен быть например такой json:

'[{"login":"11","la":"48.30369","lo":"38.033502"},{"login":"11","la":"48.30369","lo":"38.033502"},
{"login":"11","la":"48.30369","lo":"38.033502"}]'

Это будет массив объектов, а так у вас один объект изначально у него повторяются же поля.

Comment: если исходный будет таким:
'[{"login":"11","la":"48.30369","lo":"38.033502"},{"login":"11","la":"48.30369","lo":"38.033502"}, {"login":"11","la":"48.30369","lo":"38.033502"}]'
то JSON.parse не работает и выдает undefined

Comment: JSON.parse [работает][1]. Ошибка в чём-то другом.

  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/JF7NE/

Answer (score -2):

Ну а если подумать, в чем же дело? Вы пытаетесь вывести объект как строку, по этому и не работает. Попробуйте метод [toString()](http://javascript.ru/Object/toString), либо нужно просто по другому подойти к этому вопросу.

Comment: toString вызывается само если в контексте строки исполльзуется Object.

Comment: @vkovalchuk88 ага, я спутал с JSON.stringify. Но пусть уж будет так, как написал.